# Sitecore Rebuild Index: Request size exceeded Azure Search Service limits

Tags: azure, azure-search

During index rebuild at Azure, I am getting error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.RequestEntityTooLargeException:
>   Request size exceeded Azure Search Service limits --->
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException:
>   The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)

Is it something that I could solve via Sitecore settings, or should be fixed on azure side?

Comment: on which index you get this error?

Comment: I believe there is a limit on the indexing. I think I heard something about 100 or 1000 fields. Perhaps you can explore that.

Comment: are you using same azure search service in dev and qa ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue was solved by decreasing batch size, for more info you can have a look onto:

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-azure-search/customizing-azure-search .

This value can be set in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` which is living under `App_Config/Include`. Node name `cloudBatchBuilder`, simply decrease the value `maxDocuments`.

The root of the problem was huge computed strings(crawled html) we tried to push in single batch. So we met a restriction of azure which is 16mb per batch.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations around what Azure Search can do on Sitecore. These are documented thoroughly on Sitecore's Documentation Site ([Link to Doc Site Page](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/setting%20up%20and%20maintaining/search%20and%20indexing/sitecore%20azure%20search%20overview)).

That being said, RequestEntityTooLarge exception is caused because IIS is throwing a 413 Error Code. This is generally caused because of a WCF limitation which sets a default limit of 65KB for messages.

To Fix this, you need set `maxReceivedMessageSize` in your Web.config file in the `system.serviceModel` node.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
        <readerQuotas ... />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Which binding? Or do we add a binding?

Comment: This is in the web.config file.  I'm realizing it's not clear, so I will update the answer.

Comment: This may be wishful thinking, but shouldn't the default web config already have this in place? Why must we find out about this the hard way?